# Why doesn`t the code work - Adobe LiveCycle Designer - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events, adobe, livecycle-designer

I have a subform that has to duplicate itself when I press a button. This code is in the click event of the button. It is in Adobe Livecycle designer - Javascipt. Why doesn't it work ? It wasn't written by me

```
var rd = frmO.caption.value.resolveNode("#text").value;;
if (frmO.rawValue == null) {
    app.alert("Mai intai trebuie sa completati campul: " + rd + "!");
    xfa.host.setFocus(frmO);
    xfa.host.openList(frmO);
} else {

    /*
    This button will insert one instance of the repeating subform or table row.

    bCalc: Flag - true if the new instance might be referenced by other 
    calculations, otherwise false.  
    message: The error message displayed.
    */
    var bCalc = true;
    var message = "Ați atins numărul maxim de elemente permise.";
    //var err = "Trebuie sa completati toate campurile randului inainte de 
    adauga un rand nou!";
    //if (prod.name.rawValue != null && prod.supr.rawValue != null && 
    prod.norma.rawValue != null && prod.normaRed.rawValue != null &&
        prod.venit.rawValue != null) {

    // DO NOT MODIFY THE CODE BEYOND THIS POINT - 10.0.2.20120224.1.869952.867557 - Subform_Instance_Controls_IRM.xfo.p2

    var oWrapper = this.parent.parent; // The outer subform built in to the 
    object, enclosing the button group.
    var oTargetSubform = oWrapper.parent; // The subform or table row the 
    controls are intended to manipulate.
    var oManager = oTargetSubform.instanceManager; // Get the instance manager.
    var nMaxCount = oManager.occur.max; // Get the maximum 
    number of subform occurrences allowed.
    var nSubCount = oManager.count; // Get the current 
    number of instances.

    // Proceed if the maximum number of subform occurrences has not been reached.
    if((nMaxCount == "-1") || (nSubCount < nMaxCount)) {

        // Invoke the Instance Manager.
        var oNewInstance = oManager.addInstance(1);

        // Fire the form calculations.
        if (bCalc == true) {
            // Execute all the form calculations.
            xfa.form.recalculate(1);
        }

        // Move the new subform below the current one.
        var nIndexFrom = oNewInstance.index;
        var nIndexTo = oTargetSubform.index + 1;
        oManager.moveInstance(nIndexFrom, nIndexTo);
    } else {

        xfa.host.messageBox(message, "Insert Item", 3);
    }
    //}
    //else
    //app.alert(err);

    // END OF DO NOT MODIFY
}
```

I would like the subform to replicate itself when I press the button.

Comment: I formatted the code to add indentation which makes it more readable. Before and after the edit, there is a problem that the syntax highlight shows - everything after the line `//var err = "Trebuie sa completati toate campurile randului inainte de` is red because it there is an open quote there. It seems like there was commented out code and a newline was inserted breaking it into two lines which, in turn left the end uncommented with the quote character left there. Is this in the code right now or is it a product of copy/pasting it here? Because if it's present it can and will break the code.

Comment: product of copy/pasting it here

Comment: SOLVED IT...THE QUESTION CAN BE CLOSED